# Making <div>s disappear simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

My aim of the code which you'll find below is to make some kind of a filter. But for some reason it won't work.

As you can see when you try to hide the boxes when selecting the `input` box it won't work; but when you make `var x`, `var x = document.getElementById("a");` it will work. Is there a way to hide all the different boxes?

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = [document.getElementById("a"), document.getElementById("b"), document.getElementById("c")];

  if (x.style.display == 'block')
    x.style.display = 'none';
  else
    x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#a, #b, #c {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #002261;
  margin: -1px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction1()">Try to hide all


<div id="a">item a</div>
<div id="b">item b</div>
<div id="c">item c</div>
```

As you can see you can't hide all the boxes simultaneously.

Comment: `x` is an array that doesn't have a style property. try using `x.forEach`.

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a list(`[]`) and then trying to style the list itself, not its contents.

JavaScript provides an easy list method for this, `forEach()`:

```
function myFunction1() {
  var x = [document.getElementById("a"), document.getElementById("b"), document.getElementById("c")];
  x.forEach(function(item) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(item).display === 'block') item.style.display = 'none';
    else item.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
```

[See this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/xwmaqY)
**Note:** your code had a minor bug in getting the style, `item.style.display` only gets inline styles, so the first time you call the function it will not hide the element. I fixed it in the above code and codepen with `window.getComputedStyle(item).display`.

Comment: @OlivierGroeneveld glad I could help :) I just updated my answer to fix a small bug